# Do non-resident aliens have to pay US taxes on dividends from ADRs?

Tags: united-states, taxes, dividends, non-resident, adr

If a US non-resident alien owns some shares of an ADR that pays dividends, does the US government collect any tax on those dividends? I understand that, for non-resident aliens, there is a 30% tax on cash dividends for US stocks (assuming no applicable tax treaties). Is it the same for ADRs?